# Counting sessions in a foreach loop in not working PHP

Tags: php, session

I am trying to count all my products that is stored in a session called `$_SESSION['product'.$id];`.
But its not counting, its counting like this 1 1 1 1.
So its counting 1 of each product id separated.
My foreach loop...

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if($value > 0){
        if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
            $length = strlen($name) -8;
            $item_id = substr($name,8 , $length);

            $query = "SELECT * 
                 FROM gallery2 
                 WHERE gallery2.id =".escape_string($item_id). "";
            $run_item = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_item)){ 
                $vari   = $rows['variante'];
                $num    = $rows['title'];
                $id     = $rows['id'];

                if(!isset($_SESSION['icms'.$id])) {
                    $_SESSION['icms'.$id]='0';
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['icms'.$id];
                }

                //some code here

                $subtotal=$value * $_SESSION['icms'.$id];
                $cost=$_SESSION['icms'.$id];

                $product = '
        <tr>
          <td style="width:100px; "><img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" style="width:90%;border: 1px solid black;"></td>
          <td>'.$num.''.$vari.'</td>
          //some code here
          <td class="product'.$id.'">'.$value.'</td>
          <td class="cost" data-id="'.$id.'" >R$:'.$cost.'</td>
          <td class="subtotal" data-id="'.$id.'">R$:'.number_format($subtotal, 2, '.', '') .'</td>
          <td> 
             '.$btn_add.' '.$btn_remove.' '.$btn_delete.'
          </td>
        </tr>';
                echo $product;  
                //some closing brackets
```

Why this is happening?
What i tried:

```
print_r(count($_SESSION['product_'.$item_id])) ;
print_r(count($name)) ;
print_r(count($product)) ;
print_r(count($value)) ;
```

[image]

Comment: It will return always 1, because such variables are strings, not arrays.

Comment: Instead of using `$_SESSION['product'_ . $id]`, why don't you just store an array in `$_SESSION['products']`, where the keys of the array are `$id`?

Comment: BTW, `substr($name, 8)` will go to the end, you don't need to calculate `strlen($name)-8`.

Comment: I am trying to count all `$_SESSION['product_'.$id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$product_count = count(array_filter(array_keys($_SESSION), function($x) {
    return substr($x, 0, 8) == 'product_';
}));
```

But as I mentioned in a comment, it would probably be better if you redesigned your data. Instead of storing each product in a separate session variable, store them in an array. So instead of `$_SESSION['product_'.$i]` you would have `$_SESSION['products'][$i]`. Then you wouldn't need the code that checks whether the session variable beings with `product_`, you could just use

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $id => $value)
```

And to get the number of products, it would just be `count($_SESSION['products'])`.

Comment: A thing i just saw is a mistake of mine...I was using count inside of my foreach loop so i put out of it, but not out of my cart function.

Comment: I don't see that in the code in the question. How could it make sense to do it inside the loop, since you want to put the count in the heading of the table?